# Output of cat to bash numeric variable

Tags: linux, bash, casting, numeric, cat

I have a set of files, each containing a single (integer) number, which is the number of files in the directory of the same name (without the .txt suffix) - the result of a `wc` on each of the directories.

I would like to sum the numbers in the files. I've tried:

```
i=0; 
find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | while read j; do i=$i+`cat $j.txt`; done
echo $i
```

But the answer is 0. If I simply `echo` the output of `cat`:

```
i=0; find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n' | while read j; do echo `cat $j.txt`; done
```

The values are there:

```
1313
1528
13465
22258
7262
6162
...
```

Presumably I have to cast the output of `cat` somehow?

[EDIT]

I did find my own solution in the end:

```
i=0; 
for j in `find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%f\n'`; do 
    expr $((i+=$(cat $j.txt))); 
done; 

28000
30250
...
...
647185
649607
```

but the accepted answer is neater as it doesn't output along the way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you're summing the output of `cat` should work. However, you're getting `0` because your `while` loop is running in a subshell and so the variable that stores the sum goes out of scope once the loop ends. For details, see [BashFAQ/024](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).

Here's one way to solve it, using [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) (instead of pipes):

```
SUM=0
while read V; do
    let SUM="SUM+V" 
done < <(find -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec cat "{}.txt" \;)
```

Note that I've taken the liberty of changing the find/cat/sum operations, but your approach should work fine as well.

Answer (score 1):

My one-liner solution without the need of find :

```
echo $(( $(printf '%s\n' */ | tr -d / | xargs -I% cat "%.txt" | tr '\n' '+')0 ))
```

Comment: What's the benefit of not using find?

Comment: It's faster to use printf instead of find ;)